# Need more clarification on upgrading to 4GB on an Acer Aspire 5102WLMI

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, acer-aspire

In one of the questions before ([from October 2009](https://superuser.com/questions/63233/4gb-memory-upgrade-for-acer-aspire-5102wlmi)) the question has been answered how to get an ACER Aspire 5102WLMI with 4GB of memory up and running beyond POST. I have exactly that problem, but don’t get it resolved despite your answer. I really don't know which PCB tracks have to be shortened and the 'jumper' J2 doesn't exist. There is a JP2, but that seems to be no jumper to me.

I have made a photograph of the PCB tracks under the DIMMs. Would you please be so kind to give me a clue what to do (referring to that picture)?

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: Photo of PCB tracks under the DIMMs]

Comment: Upload the image to imageshack.us post the link to it when you edit your post, you might also link to the 2009 question you spoke of.

Comment: Upload the photo to something like tinypic and paste it as a comment to your questions someone will edit it in.

Answer (score 0):

All,

the problem has been solved.
For me it worked to reset bios (by shortcutting internal battery) and to assure that the 2 Dimms are really compatible (read completely identical at chip level, compare numbers!).
After replacing two non-identical ones (the store was co-operative), the system works with 4GB (3.5GB usable for a 32 bits system).
Thank you all.

Hub

Comment: Hi @Hub I merged your accounts, just so your know!