# Maximum Memory for Acer Aspire 5672wlmi

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade, acer-aspire

I wanted to upgrade the memory in my Acer Aspire 5672wlmi. By default, there are 2 x 1GB DDR2 installed and I wanted to upgrade to 3GB, so I bought a 2GB DDR2 PC667.

When I replace one of the existing modules with the new one (1x1GB + 1x2GB), the PC won't boot anymore (screen stays dark).
If I remove the existing 1GB module and only insert the new one, everything works fine.

So I see 2 possibilites:

- The aspire 5670 series only support up to 2GB
- I can not mix a 1GB and a 2GB module and therefore have to buy a second 2GB so I can upgrade do 2x2GB.

So my questions are:

1. Which of the two assumptions is true?
2. Does my notebook even support 4GB ?

Some further notes:

- [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/63233/4gb-memory-upgrade-for-acer-aspire-5102wlmi) is very similar. It seems the solution was a BIOS reset. Maybe I have to try that for my notebook too? Here, they mention that mixed sticks worked fine on a similar model.
- [Crucial Memory adviser](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Aspire%205670) also shows a 4GB kit.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well, guess I will never really find out as my dear old aspire decided to blow up it's graphics card today. RIP.

Answer (score 0):

According to this CNet [review](http://www.cnet.com/laptops/acer-aspire-5672wlmi-15/4505-3121_7-31752516.html), that model supports a maximum of 2GB of RAM.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found different answers to that. This pages for example mention 4GB maximum: http://www.fixya.com/support/t4716209-max_supported_memory_acer_aspire_5672 / http://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/model/Acer~Aspire+Notebook~5672. So I don't know what to believe.

Comment: the reason you found a different answer is that you are looking at the wrong model.  You say you have a "5672wlmi", but your link in the comment is to a "5672".  They are ***not*** the same model.

Comment: Ah, you're absolutely right. Anyway, same page also give 4GB for the wlmi model: http://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/model/Acer~Aspire+Notebook~5672WLMi ;-)

Comment: interesting...  still I would believe the evidence in front of you:  more than 2 gb does not work.

Comment: You're probably right. But since the pages have different opinions, I still have hope that a BIOS reset or a BIOS upgrade would help. Let's see if someone has experience with the exact model...

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same model and recently i needed some extra ram for some processing. So i replaced its 2 x 1GB modules with 2 x 2GB ones from a Dell and computer started and worked ok, although BIOS can only see 3GB. So I guess 3GB is the limit.